# Add information to existing xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq

To add information to a excisting xml file I have this code:

I have a problem at row "IEnumerable rows = root.Descendants("History");" in the else statement. See comment..

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
private static void CreateXMLFile(string text, string time)
    {
        lastID++;

        if (!(File.Exists(path + @"\CM.xml")))
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlNode docNode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
            doc.AppendChild(docNode);

            //Create first node
            XmlNode ClipboardHistoryNode = doc.CreateElement("ClipBoardHistory");
            doc.AppendChild(ClipboardHistoryNode);

            //Create second node
            XmlNode HistoryNode = doc.CreateElement("History");
            XmlAttribute idAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("ID");
            idAttribute.Value = lastID.ToString();
            XmlAttribute textAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("Text");
            textAttribute.Value = text;
            XmlAttribute timeAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("Time");
            timeAttribute.Value = time;
            HistoryNode.Attributes.Append(idAttribute);
            HistoryNode.Attributes.Append(textAttribute);
            HistoryNode.Attributes.Append(timeAttribute);

            ClipboardHistoryNode.AppendChild(HistoryNode);

            //Save file at the executing location

            doc.Save(path + @"\CM.xml");
        }
        else
        {
               XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(path + @"\CM.xml");
               XElement root= xDocument.Element("History");
               IEnumerable<XElement> rows = root.Descendants("History"); //Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
               XElement firstRow= rows.First();
               firstRow.AddBeforeSelf(
               new XElement("ID", lastID,
               new XElement("Text", text,
               new XElement("Time", time))));
               xDocument.Save(path + @"\CM.xml");
        }
    }
```

Used this(see accepted answer): [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20922835/appending-an-existing-xml-file-with-xmlwriter)

What is wrong in this code?

**EDIT**

Current XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ClipBoardHistory>
    <History ID="15" Text="ClipboardManager.vshost.exe" Time="10:05" />
</ClipBoardHistory>
```

Comment: can you show the xml?

Comment: @currarpickt Please see edit!

Comment: Change the `XElement root= xDocument.Element("History");` to `XElement root= xDocument.Root;` or remove the `XElement root` and change the `rows` to `IEnumerable<XElement> rows = xDocument.Root.Descendants("History");`